# How to calculate distance without numpy

Tags: python, list, 3d, gps

```
 myList =  [[0, 0, 0], #0
       [6.888437030500963, 5.159088058806049, -1.5885683833831], #1
       [2.0667720363602307, 5.384582486178219, -3.4898856343748133], #2
       [7.742743817055683, 1.4508370077567676,-3.957946551327696],#3
       [9.410384606156306, 9.613094711663472, -3.864209434979891],#4
       [5.047141494150383, 14.72917879480795, -1.4968295014732576],#5
       [0.05726832139919402,22.924103914172754, 8.158880019279806],#6
       [6.261613041330982, 30.96742292296441,4.361831405666459], #7
       [10.858248006533554, 38.94418868232428, 8.041510043975286],#8
       [10.30110231558782, 30.958212843691598, 6.724946753050958],#9
       [12.518841784463852,39.21843390844956, 16.057074108466132]]#10

import math

def distance (myList):

    dist = math.sqrt ((xa-xb)**2 + (ya-yb)**2 + (za-zb)**2)
    return dist

print("Distance:",(distance(myList)))
```

How can I calculate the distance of all that points but without NumPy? I understand how to do it with 2 but not with more than 2

Comment: Iterate over all possible combination of two points and call the function to calculate distance between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find the euclidian distance with the equation: 
d = sqrt((px1 - px2)^2 + (py1 - py2)^2 + (pz1 - pz2)^2)

Implementing in python:

```
import math

def dist(list):
  cummulativeDist = 0

  # iterate over sets of points
  for i in range(len(list) - 1):
    coordInit = list[i]
    coordFinal = list[i+1]

    # distance from one pt to the next
    dist = math.sqrt(((coordInit[0] - coordFinal[0]) ** 2) 
                    + ((coordInit[1] - coordFinal[2]) ** 2) 
                    + ((coordInit[2] - coordFinal[2]) ** 2)) 

    cummulativeDist += dist

  return cummulativeDist

print(f"Distance: {dist(myList)}")
```

This will take the 3 dimensional distance and from one point to the next and return the total distance traveled.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

def distance (myList):
  distlist=[]
  for a in myList:
    for b in myList:
      dist = math.sqrt ((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2 + (a[2]-b[2])**2)
      distlist.append(dist)
  return distlist

print("Distance:",(distance(myList)))
```

You have to append each result to a list you previously generated or you will store only the last value

Comment: Distance: [0.0, 8.75158864609029, 6.741259299400485, 8.815914628828788, 13.996393925886174, 15.641702074514633, 24.332799738160624, 31.893802745683463, 41.22156311547659, 33.31288880032608,..............

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's wrong?  What are you expecting the answer to be for the distance between the first and second list?

Comment: Each point is a list with the x,y and z coordinate in this order.  The coordinates describe a hike, the coordinates are given in meters--> distance(myList): Should return the whole distance travelled during the hike

Comment: Man... Add this comment to your question. It's pretty incomplete in this case

Answer (score 0):

```py
from math import sqrt

def euclidean_distance(x, y):
    return sqrt(sum((px - py)**2  for px, py in zip(x,y)))
    
euclidean_distance(x,y)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.